# Windows Phone 7 BackgroundAudioPlayer Buffering Progress always returning 0 or 1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, background-agents

Actually I'm developing a live streaming app for WP7 and I'm facing a problem. I'm trying to update the UI so the user can get live information about the buffering progress but the BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.BufferingProgress is not reporting the exact percentage of data received. it always returns 0 or 1 (100%). I'm using the RC version of the SDK and I'm not sure if it has been fixed in the RTM.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [may be a known issue](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/90807/543852.aspx) which doesn't seem to have [been resolved in RTM](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/89707.aspx). Out of curiosity, if the stream is live and continuous, wouldn't it be impossible for `BufferingProgress` to determine how complete the download is (since a continuous stream would be theoretically infinite in length)?

Comment: The forum links were broken when they updated it to the Dev Center. You can search for the thread in the forums and edit this post if you like, but they essentially just said that it hasn't been resolved in RTM (Mango).

Comment: Im am here, trying to use this with Windows Phone 8, and the issue still is there.